# Relations on the set of all functions from Z to Z

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I know a similar question has been asked before, but I don't get what a relation on a set of functions means exactly...

The problem is determine if the relation $R=\{(f,g)|f(0)=g(0)\text{ or }f(1)=g(1)\}$ on the set of all functions from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ is an equivalence relation...

But the confusing part is that the ordered pair contains $f$ and $g$, not $f(x)$ or $g(x)$.

Comment: Don't be confused, $f$ and $f(x)$ are the same thing.

Comment: Ok, get that...but how can you determine if its transitive? There are only two functions, f and g.

Comment: @ohbrobig Just for the record: What Ivan said isn't really true, but I suppose it does help you understand the question better ($f$ is a function, $f(x)$ is not a function but an integer).

Comment: The relation is on the set of all function from the integers to itself, call this set $X$. Then your relation $R$ is a subset of $X\times X$. For transitive, take $(f,g),(g,h)\in R$ and determine if $(f,h)\in R$.

Comment: @Stefan Sure, I should have added "_For the purpose of this problem..._"

Comment: @ohbrobig No, there are as many functions as you want. Introduce a third function $h$, suppose that it coincides with $f$ at 0 and with $g$ at 1. What can be said about $f$ and $g$? Are they equivalent?